# I want to add html text filed value in other text filed value will changed

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to set PHP variable in  HTML text field  during other text field value will be changed.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="refrence" id="refrence" onkeydown="myFunction(event)" 
         placeholder="Reference" autocomplete="off">
```

javaScript

```
   <script>
          function myFunction(event) {
           var x = event.keyCode;
             if (x == 17) {  

               var name = document.getElementById("companyName");
               var address = document.getElementById("address");
               alert("df");
               name.value = "<?php echo $invoiceValues['order_receiver_name']; ? 
                             >; 
               address.value = "<?php echo invoiceValues['order_receiver_address']; ?>; 

              }
            }

  </script>
```

php code

```
public function getrefer() {
   $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->invoicevendortable 
                 . " WHERE reference = '" . $_SESSION['refrence'] . "'";

   return $this->getData($sqlQuery);
}
```

Comment: is your javascript being parsed by PHP? If so then myFunction would always write the value your order_receiver_* variables had at the time that code was parsed .. but I suspect you're simply trying to push the variable value into the secondary DOM elements .. you need to read the *current* value via JS!!

Comment: Oh .. and you should NEVER trust the values you get from forms or other user input .. so I *hope* your $_SESSION['reference'] value has undergone some sanity checks before being passed into your query! Or have you forgotten:https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the current value via JS; PHP only gets parsed on page load!

```
var refDomElement = document.querySelector( '#reference' )
    , useDomElement = document.querySelector( '#companySomething' )
useDomElement.value = refDomElement.value
```